# Back colour of button not changing when updated in FOR loop

Tags: vb.net

Working in Visual Studio 2017, in Visual Basic in a Windows Form App (.NET Framework).

I'm trying to create a button where the back-colour of the button is a changing gradient. I made a simple algorithm to make the gradient change, and a time delay function to wait between the colour changes. However, the colour just doesn't update within the for loops as it carries out and only shows the final result, so how to fix it? Think it's an issue with the time delay function, but not sure, anyways here's the code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Public Sub bg_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles bg.MouseClick

        Dim r As Integer = 241
        Dim g As Integer = 121
        Dim b As Integer = 121

        For x = g To r
            g += 1
            bg.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)
            timeDelay(0.01)
        Next

        For x = b To r
            r -= 1
            bg.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)
            timeDelay(0.01)
        Next

        For x = b To g
            b += 1
            bg.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)
            timeDelay(0.01)
        Next

        For x = r To g
            g -= 1
            bg.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)
            timeDelay(0.01)
        Next

        For x = g To b
            r += 1
            bg.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)
            timeDelay(0.01)
        Next

        For x = g To b
            b -= 1
            bg.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)
            timeDelay(0.01)
        Next

        MessageBox.Show("Finished")
    End Sub
    Public Sub timeDelay(ByVal secondsDelayedBy As Double)
        Dim stopwatch As New Stopwatch
        Dim endtimer = False
        stopwatch.Start()
        Do Until endtimer = True
            If stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > (secondsDelayedBy * 1000) Then
                endtimer = True
                stopwatch.Stop()
            End If
        Loop
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Research the 'Control.Invalidate` and `Control.Refresh` methods.

Comment: `research ain't my thang`  Please read [How much research is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1070452)  Also read [ask] and take the [tour] - this is not an anything goes forum.

Comment: Translated = "I don't feel like looking this up, but since my time is more valuable than yours, I'll let you do it for me".

Answer (score 1):

This is hapening because your code is running on the UI Thread, and locking it without refreshing the interface, and the only time it actually shows any update is when the code finish running.

To update your button color, you could as @TnTinMn mention on his comment use a 
`bg.Refresh` inside your for loops, or use an async sub and run it on a separated thread.

Using `bg.Refresh` your loops will look like this :

```
For x = g To r
    g += 1
    bg.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)
    bg.Refresh()
    timeDelay(0.01)
Next
```

Using an async method:

```
Public Async Sub bg_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles bg.MouseClick

    Dim r As Integer = 241
    Dim g As Integer = 121
    Dim b As Integer = 121

    Await Task.Run(Sub()
                       For x = g To r
                           g += 1
                           SetButtonColor(bg, Color.FromArgb(r, g, b))
                           timeDelay(0.01)
                       Next

                       'Other for Loops...

                   End Sub)

    MessageBox.Show("Finished")
End Sub

Public Sub SetButtonColor(Button As Button, Color As Color)
    If Button.InvokeRequired Then
        Button.Invoke(Sub() SetButtonColor(Button, Color))
    Else
        Button.BackColor = Color
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

Change all your '`timeDelay(0.01)`' calls to:  `Threading.Thread.Sleep(10) : Application.DoEvents()`

Comment: `Application.DoEvents()` = bad advice.

Comment: Each to their own but for this simple task it works a treat.